# one central custom error_page for all sites in nginx

Tags: nginx

We have many sites in our nginx config file and we would like to use a custom error_page, but the same one for all sites.

I tried setting it in http{} to /path/to/my/404.html. I noticed that it looks inside the 'root' directory (so /path/to/my/root/path/to/my/404.html)

Is there a way that I can use one 404 file for all my virtual hosts without having to symlink a file in each directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an Alias directive to the location:

```
location /404.html {
  alias /shared/files/404.html
}

error_page 404 /404.html
```

That should do it.